Hypergeometric-like distribution but where non-successes are replaced?
I'm working on a card game and say the deck has C cards where the player draws 3 cards every turn, picks a card, and the rest are shuffled back into the deck. They can do this N times. There are X of special cards which the player will nearly always pick if drawn. I'm trying to determine the best value of X to ensure the player sees on average around 2 or 3 of these cards in N draws.
This seems similar to what hypergeometric calculators do, but if I'm not mistaken, they assume that no cards are replaced, and binomial calculators assume all cards are replaced. I could simulate this over a couple thousand runs in a python script, but is there a good mathematical formula I could apply to think kind of problem?

There will be a formula, but it may be complicated.  A starting point would be to say that initially the probability of drawing a special card on the first turn is $1-\frac{(C-X)(C-X-1)(C-X-2)}{C(C-1)(C-2)}$, but in later turns $C$ reduces and $X$ may reduce.

Yeah, maybe the simulation rout will be the way to go.

You can compute the exact distribution by tracking the state distribution of a Markov chain. The states could consist of the total number of cards picked so far and the number of specials picked so far. The transition probabilities can be computed as per Henry's comment:
$$\frac{C - X}{C} \frac{C - X - 1}{C - 1} \frac{C - X - 2}{C - 2}$$
chance of drawing only normal cards, and one minus this amount for drawing at least one special.
Here is an example implementation using my Icepool Python package:
from icepool import Deck, Die, tupleize

initial_deck_size = 36
initial_specials = 4

def next_state(total_picked, specials_picked):
    remaining_specials = initial_specials - specials_picked
    remaining_normals = initial_deck_size - total_picked - remaining_specials
    deck = Deck({'normal': remaining_normals, 'special': remaining_specials})
    return tupleize(total_picked + 1,
        specials_picked + (deck.deal(3) >= ['special']))

state = Die([(0, 0)])

for i in range(21):
    output(state.marginals[1])
    state = state.map(next_state)

You can run this in your browser here.


I'm not familiar with that package, but at a first glance this looks absolutely spot on. Thank you!
